# Rearrange words to match first and last letters

Tags: c++, graph-theory

How to write C++ code to rearrange word order such that the first letter of each word, except the first, is equal to the last letter of the previous word?

Note: this question sounds very specific and of little practical value.  However it is easy to explain and understand, and the technique required to solve it can be applied to several problems requiring finding a complete path that visits every 'node' exactly once through a graph that models constraints or obstacles.  These problems can be intimidatingly hard to understand, but are straightforward to solve once the technique of spanning tree followed by a depth first search is known.  For code that solves several real world problems using the same approach, see https://github.com/JamesBremner/obstacles

Details:

*Input* a list of words, one word per line, all letters lower case a to z

*Output* an ordered list of words such that the first letter of each word, except the first, is equal to the last letter of the previous word. All the words from the list must be used, each exactly once. The words mentioned several times must be used that number of times.

Comment: This post can't really function as a reference for future look-ups as the problem posed is highly specific. What is the motivation behind this post?

Comment: The motivation is to answer the question.  Is there some problem with specific questions? General question can only get general answers which are usually not very useful.

Comment: BTW I have come across this question several times, so I thought it would be helpful to answer it once and for all in a complete way.  Also, this technique can be applied to several problems in route planning, which is how I first came across it.

Comment: FYI here is an example of applying this technique to route planning around obstacles https://github.com/JamesBremner/obstacles

Comment: @StackDanny I have edited my answer to explain that the solution is also generally useful.

Comment: I assumed it doesn't add any measurable value to this site, and will probably get buried. I think it's not great to enable many of these posts, as otherwise everyone is also inclined to post their specific case and therefore the site would get flooded. However, since it is more than a trivial problem, as you have shown by adding informations, I can see how this would add value to the site.

Comment: @StackDanny Your assumption is one that far too many people make on this site.  I prefer to assume that if people take the trouble to post something, then there is a good chance they know more about what they are talking about than I do.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I also think it's crucial to always provide this information in the post. Not only to show motivation, but also to help others find the post through mentioned keywords. ( I would retract my downvote, but can't, since it requires an edit on the question. Maybe rephrase some of the question / add the github link? The title is also quite verbose. )

Answer (score -1):

Algorithm:

- Construct a directed graph by connecting words that have matching first and last letters ( e.g abc -> cde )
- Find a spanning tree in the graph.  ( If spanning tree cannot be found, the words cannot be arranged as specified )
- LOOP N over words

  - Do a depth first search of the spanning tree starting at N
  - IF search reached every word

    - OUTPUT words in order they were reached.

This algorithm is generally useful and can be applied to problems in route planning around obstacles ( e.g. https://github.com/JamesBremner/obstacles )

Here is the code to implement the algorithm:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

class cGraph;

/// @brief Spanning tree
class cTree
{
    cGraph &myGraph;

    /// @brief  links in spanning tree
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> myLink;

    std::vector<bool> myVisited;

    /// @brief links arranged so last matched next first
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> myArrange;

public:
    cTree(cGraph &g)
        : myGraph(g)
    {
    }

    void add(int n1, int n2)
    {
        myLink.push_back(std::make_pair(n1, n2));
    }
    int nodeCount();

    std::string text();

    /// @brief Depth first search starting at a link
    /// @param link
    /// @return true if every word was reached
    bool dfs(
        const std::pair<int, int> &link);

    /// @brief arrange words into required order
    ///
    /// The last letter of each word must be the
    /// same as the first letter of the next word
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> arrange();
};

class cGraph
{
    std::vector<std::string> myWord;
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> myAdj;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> myArrange;

public:
    void setSize(int s)
    {
        myAdj.resize(s, std::vector<bool>(s, false));
    }
    void addLink(int n1, int n2)
    {
        myAdj[n1][n2] = true;
    }

    void read(const std::string &fname);

    void constructAdjacencyMatrix();

    int wordCount() const
    {
        return myWord.size();
    }
    std::string word(int idx) const
    {
        return myWord[idx];
    }

    std::vector<int> sources(int n);
    std::vector<int> targets(int n);

    void arrange();

    void displayArrange();

private:
    cTree spanningTree();
};

int cTree::nodeCount()
{
    std::set<int> nodes;
    for (auto &l : myLink)
    {
        nodes.insert(l.first);
        nodes.insert(l.second);
    }
    return nodes.size();
}

std::string cTree::text()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (auto &l : myLink)
        ss << myGraph.word(l.first)
           << " -> "
           << myGraph.word(l.second)
           << " ";
    return ss.str();
}

std::vector<int> cGraph::sources(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> ret;
    int n1idx = -1;
    for (auto &vl : myAdj)
    {
        n1idx++;
        int n2idx = -1;
        for (bool l : vl)
        {
            n2idx++;
            if (n2idx == n)
                if (l)
                    ret.push_back(n1idx);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
std::vector<int> cGraph::targets(int n)
{
    std::vector<int> ret;
    int n2idx = -1;
    for (bool l : myAdj[n])
    {
        n2idx++;
        if (l)
            ret.push_back(n2idx);
    }

    return ret;
}

cTree cGraph::spanningTree()
{
    cTree mySpanningTree(*this);
    std::vector<bool> visited(myAdj.size(), false);

    // add initial arbitrary link
    int v, w;
    for (v = 0; v < myAdj.size(); v++)
    {
        auto vt = targets(v);
        if (vt.size())
        {
            w = vt[0];
            mySpanningTree.add(v, w);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (v == myAdj.size())
        throw std::runtime_error("no links");

    visited[v] = true;
    visited[w] = true;

    // while nodes remain outside of span
    bool fdone = false;
    while (!fdone)
    {
        // loop over nodes in span
        for (v = 0; v < myAdj.size(); v++)
        {
            if (!visited[v])
                continue;

            // loop over nodes not in span
            fdone = true;
            for (w = 0; w < myAdj.size(); w++)
            {
                if (visited[w])
                    continue;

                fdone = false;

                if (myAdj[v][w])
                {
                    mySpanningTree.add(v, w);
                    visited[w] = true;
                }
                if (myAdj[w][v])
                {
                    mySpanningTree.add(w, v);
                    visited[w] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (v == myAdj.size())
            fdone = true;
    }

    if (mySpanningTree.nodeCount() < myAdj.size())
        throw std::runtime_error(
            "Spanning tree incomplete: no solution available\n");

    // std::cout << "\n"
    //           << mySpanningTree.text() << "\n";

    return mySpanningTree;
}

void cGraph::arrange()
{
    // Find a spanning tree and search it for a matching word arrangement
    // throw exception if no arrangement possible
    myArrange = spanningTree().arrange();
}

void cGraph::displayArrange()
{
    // display the arrangement found
    std::cout << "arrange into "
              << word(myArrange[0].first) << " ";
    for (auto &l : myArrange)
        std::cout << word(l.second) << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

void cGraph::read(const std::string &fname)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(fname);
    if (!ifs.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "cannot open input\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    std::string word;
    ifs >> word; // skip count
    while (ifs.good())
    {
        ifs >> word;
        myWord.push_back(word);
        std::cout << word << "\n";
    }
    setSize(myWord.size());
}

void cGraph::constructAdjacencyMatrix()
{
    int widx = -1;
    for (auto &w : myWord)
    {
        widx++;
        char first = w[0];
        char last = w[w.length() - 1];
        int sidx = -1;
        for (auto &src : myWord)
        {
            sidx++;
            if (sidx == widx)
                continue;
            if (src[src.length() - 1] == first)
            {
                addLink(sidx, widx);
            }
            if (src[0] == last)
            {
                addLink(widx, sidx);
            }
        }
    }
}

bool cTree::dfs(
    const std::pair<int, int> &l)
{
    myVisited[l.first] = true;
    myVisited[l.second] = true;
    bool fdone = true;
    for (bool v : myVisited)
    {
        if (!v)
        {
            fdone = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (fdone)
    {
        myArrange.push_back(l);
        return true;
    }

    auto visited_save = myVisited;
    for (const auto &lnext : myLink)
    {
        if (lnext.first == l.second)
        {
            myVisited = visited_save;
            if (dfs(lnext))
            {
                myArrange.push_back(l);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> cTree::arrange()
{
    // loop over links in spanning tree
    for (const auto &l : myLink)
    {
        // do a depth fist search through the tree
        // starting from this link
        myVisited.clear();
        myVisited.resize(myGraph.wordCount(), false);
        if (dfs(l))
        {
            // the dfs reached every word
            // reverse the order in which the words were found
            // which gives an arrangement of words in required order
            std::reverse(myArrange.begin(), myArrange.end());

            // done
            return myArrange;
        }
    }
}

main()
{
    cGraph graph;

    // read word list from file
    graph.read("input.txt");

    // connect matching words
    graph.constructAdjacencyMatrix();

    // arrange words, matching first and last letters
    graph.arrange();

    // output results
    graph.displayArrange();

    return 0;
}
```